# Validating Digital certificate using OCSP protocol

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, x509certificate, ocsp

In our website, user has the provision to login using the Digital certificate. Currently validation happens only in Web server, where it is checking the expiry date of the Certificate.

But now we wanted to implement the validation in more secure way by calling the OCSP protocol. We don't have any experience in the past to  implement the OCSP protocol for validation of Digital certificate.

I did some research and found that, Bouncy castle is the best library to make OCSP call. But i'm struggling to implement as i'm not understanding where to start. Could any one please direct me in the right path. Code snippet will be a good help.

.net is our front end technology.

Comment: Does certificate include OCSP url in AIA extension? If yes, then you can use `X509Chain` class to build chain and perform revocation checking.

Comment: @Crypt32 Yes, it does contains the OCSP url. Can you share code snippet to do that.

Comment: Then take a look at `X509Chain` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain(v=vs.110).aspx instantiate the object, pass certificate and call `Build` method. The rest will be done automatically.

Comment: Your question has lots of words which suggest a less than adequate understanding of certificates in general. OCSP is not some panacea that will solve your authentication problems. OCSP checks to see if a certificate has been *explicitly revoked* by the certification authority. That is only one step of several that are required to properly authenticate a user.